# Triggering CSS3 Keyframes with javascript multiple times

Tags: javascript, animation

I am triggering CSS3 Keyframes with javascript but its working for with first call after that any call to that function doesn't animate my div.

Here the Javascript code

```
function animateShare (imgSrc){            
    var share = document.getElementById("shareTools");
    share.style.animation = "testAnimate 1s ease-in-out 0s"
    //shareTools.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
```

Sample of the issue (Click red box to preview)

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function animateBox(){
    box.style.animation = "box 1s ease-in-out 0s";
  }
```

```css
#box{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  }

@keyframes box {
    50%{width:300px;}
  }
```

```html
<div id='box' onclick='animateBox()'><div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gwegv7th/)

I want it to animate everytime i call this function.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle to check this out

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use well known hack: **destroy and create element to reset animation**.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function animateBox(){

    //destroy and create hack
    document.body.removeChild(box);
    document.body.appendChild(box);

    box.style.animation = "box 1s ease-in-out 0s";
  }
```

```css
#box{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  }

@keyframes box {
    50%{width:300px;}
  }
```

```html
<div id='box' onclick='animateBox()'><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still interested by this there is another trick that works:

**Changing the dataset value to something it has never been, and then use a css matching on that data.**

I used this technique when animating the collapsing/uncollapsing of a menu, which of course can happen multiple times. Here's how I did it:

```
#menu[data-closed^="1"]{
    animation:menu_closing;
}
#menu[data-closed^="0"]{
    animation:menu_opening;
}
```

So the animation is based on the first character of the dataset (1 or 0).

Then in the click event that wants to close/open the menu:

```
var closed = menu_ele.dataset.closed // closed right now
    ? parseInt( menu_ele.dataset.closed.substr(0,1) )
    : 0; // assuming menu is initialized open
var counter = menu_ele.dataset.closed // nb of times the menu was closed or open
    ? parseInt( menu_ele.dataset.closed.substr(1) )
    : 0;
menu_ele.dataset.closed = ''+(1-closed)+(counter+1);
```

This way the "closed" dataset variable changes like this at every click:

```
11 (closing for the first time)
02 (reopening for the first time)
13
04
15
06
...
```

The first digit indicates whether it is currently closed, while all the rest is a counter to make the value new every time.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your code - after first call it does nothing, becouse it already changed animation property of that element.

According to [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/):

```
function animateShare (imgSrc){            
    var share = document.getElementById("shareTools");
    share.style.animation = "testAnimate 1s ease-in-out 0s";
    shareTools.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    shareTools.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in the body section after the element for which the animation is being played-

```
<script>
document.getElementById('shareTools').addEventListener("animationend", function () {

        this.removeAttribute("style");
    })

</script>
```

or if you dont want to remove style attribute ,because you have other css than animation then create a class and add class dynimacally and remove it as above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the animation by just removing the `animation` property from the styles of the element after the animation has complete - removing the element is unnecessary. In my example, I set the duration in JS, but you could just as easily add an `animationend` hook to keep it simpler.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwegv7th/4/)

```js
var duration = 1000;
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', function onClick(ev) {
  var el = this;
  el.style.animation = 'box ' + (duration / 1000 + 's') + ' ease-in-out';
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.animation = ''
  }, duration);
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes box {
  50% {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='box'><div>
```